# PYTHON - Matplotlib: plot different datasets in a graph with colormap + axis and label width

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, axes, colormap

I am trying to create a short script to plot some data from different Excel files.
As these are overlapping on the same graph, I would like to use a color map to differentiate between each plot.
I have tried different approaches but I do not understand how to get what I need, as it returns the plots using only the first color.

I have been trying to change axes and labels weight as well without using subplots() as this would return a plot after every for cycle.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import os
from os import path
import sys
import openpyxl

xlsx_files=glob.glob(r'C:\Users\path\**\*.xlsx'
)
xlsx_files.sort()

print(xlsx_files)
print(type(xlsx_files))
df_frames=[]
print('Number of plots: ', len(xlsx_files))
n=len(xlsx_files)
m=n

for file in xlsx_files:
    print('Plot: ', m)
    m=m-1
    df_frames.append(pd.read_excel(file))
    all_frames=pd.concat(df_frames)
    print(df_frames)
    ph_loops=all_frames[all_frames['Read (V)']==-0.5]
    x = ph_loops['Write (V)']
    y = ph_loops['ph0 (o)']
    colors=plt.cm.winter(np.linspace(0, 1, n))
    for i in range (n):
        plt.plot(x, y, c=colors[i], marker='.', linewidth=0.5, markersize=2)
        plt.tick_params(axis='y', colors='xkcd:orange')
        plt.xlabel('Write (V)', fontsize=12, weight='bold')
        plt.ylabel('Phase (deg)', color='xkcd:orange', fontsize=12, weight='bold')
        plt.title(file+'\n')
        plt.tick_params(width=2)
        plt.rcParams['axes.linewidth']=2
    plt.plot()
plt.show()
```

[Graph of multiple plots with incorrect coloring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MviAU.png)

Comment: Now you are drawing each curve `n` times, with `n` different colors, but only the last one (green) green will stay visible. Maybe you could remove `for i in range (n):` (and also remove the indentation of the statements inside), and call `plt.plot(x, y, c=colors[m], ....)`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Joahn. What you said in the first point makes sense. I have tried however to follow your input and now it does not uses the colormap and just gives back blue plots.

Comment: Depending on what's in your files, `ph_loops=all_frames[all_frames['Read (V)']==-0.5]` might be empty or contain only a few rows.

Comment: Each loop (excel file) contains about 20-30 data points, but the code is iterated for over 50 plots. You can see the image I posted in the question behind the link.

Comment: Upon checking I printed colors[n-1] and it shows the same color used for all the plots, so now surely it does not iterate, compared to the previous case